# Using AppUI in Function

Tags: php

I am translating a website and I need to input `$AppUI->_('')` to make translation in system admin. But, somehow I can't use it in this function.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my script and I hope you will help me:

```
public function BeginCalc()
{
    if($this->getActive())
    {
        echo $AppUI->_('Calculating');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_BeginCalculation();
        echo "Calculation has been started";
    }
}
```

And, when I use like this I get error `Fatal error: Call to a member function _() on a non-object in`. Tried to search in Stackowerflow but answers there haven't helped me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AppUI does not exists in this scope. If it's global variable, you need to import it with global keyword.

But i'd rather advise you to make $AppUI object a singleton and reference to it by AppUI::getInstance()->_('Calculating');

Comment: SHould i use it like this? echo AppUI::getInstance()->_('Calculating');

Comment: Yep, but you have to moify your AppUP class first